# How to make a npm package out of a custom react-native native module for Android?

Tags: android, npm, react-native

**My general question:** I built a native component for react-native Android. It has own dependencies and such. I followed instructions to edit the package.json, removed the dependencies of react-native and am now testing the package. Is there anything specific to follow in the case of a package for react-native?

---

**The errors/warnings I get:**

Let's say the module I'm building is called `react-native-mymodule`.

Commands I ran:

$ npm install react-native-mymodule
$ rnpm link react-native-mymodule

When running `react-native run-android`, at the step `:react-native-mymodule:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets` it throws the following error:

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^    

Error: Cannot find module '/path/to/my/test/project/node_modules/react-native-mymodule/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
    at startup (node.js:146:18)
    at node.js:404:3
:react-native-mymodule:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
```

Does this mean, I have to generate a signed APK for my native module? If so, why is this necessary when creating a native module?

I additionally get the following warning four times:

```
WARNING: Dependency test_project:react-native-mymodule:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: /path/to/my/test_project/node_modules/react-native-mymodule/android/app/build/outputs/apk/react-native-mymodule-release-unsigned.apk
```

My search on the web and in the react-native docs have been unsuccessful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can learn from other react native like [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info), it's one of simplest `react-native` library that I can see, it just has `build.gradle`, `AndroidManifest.xml`, and two Java classes.

In you `package.json`, you don't need `react-native` in dependencies, just put it in `peerDependencies` section, or don't include it in your `package.json` file.

Comment: I don't have the react-native dependency, but somehow it wants to search for `/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js'`. I don't know why...

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file in you module? just some lines about `apply plugin: "com.android.xxx"`. I guess your configuration is `com.android.application`, it is not `com.android.library`.

Comment: I indeed had `com.android.application` in there. Changing it to `com.android.library` did not help, also removing other unnecessary stuff from the the `build.gradle` did not help.. always the same error..

Comment: Can you create a simplified project to reproduce the problem on GitHub? I don't know what's the problem, I have created some modules, and used other modules, didn't have errors like this.

Comment: ok, I'll try to do that and post a link here as soon I'm finished.

Comment: I finally got to work on this again. I figured that I only have to take the Java code which is inside the `android/app` folder inside an entire react-native project, just without the `/build` folder. Thanks!